# GZip not working in IE9

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, internet-explorer-9, spring-4

Before someone points out, yes I digged through SFO and read all links/solutions, but still I couldn't find out the issue. And that is the reason why I am creating this new post.

So, I am using Spring 4 + AngularJS w/ Tomcat 7.0.67. Trying to compress HTTP Response, since most of the time it'll be JSON data of around ~200 KB! So I created a filter to compress the response and it is perfectly working fine with all browsers except IE9!! You may ask why IE9? Because my client says so! So I got no other option.

I tried to add the Content-Encoding in response from Controller like

```
response.setHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
```

but IE failed to decrypt the data, although data is compressed like it did in other browsers!

I have even added the below lines for all request,

```
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["Accept-Encoding"] = "gzip, deflate";
```

but still not working.

Please help me understand what is the issue!

**UPDATE:**
The gzipped response size in other browsers are 14.7KB, but in IE it is 225KB, which was the uncompressed data size!

**Detailed Headers : **

```
Response Headers :
view source
Cache-Control:public, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:14624
Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date:Mon, 18 Jan 2016 11:48:03 GMT
Expires:Mon, 18 Jan 2016 11:48:02 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1

Request Headers :
view source
Accept:application/json, text/html
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:0
Cookie:JSESSIONID=83DCA3B424E9F7A3EB8E165EFDA9730D; __ngDebug=true
Host:localhost:8080
Origin:http://localhost:8080
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://localhost:8080/AppName/test/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,    like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36
```

Headers from IE9

```
Request POST http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/AppName/loadClientMaster HTTP/1.1
Referer http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/AppName/test/#/menu
Accept  application/json, text/html
Accept-Language en-us
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)
Host    xx.xx.xx.xx:8080
Content-Length  0
Proxy-Connection    Keep-Alive
Pragma  no-cache
Cookie  JSESSIONID=9FBA9758381235CD22974C796449747B

Response    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server  Apache-Coyote/1.1
Cache-Control   public, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Expires Mon, 18 Jan 2016 12:10:03 GMT
Content-Type    application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date    Mon, 18 Jan 2016 12:10:04 GMT
X-Cache MISS from PROXYNEW
X-Cache-Lookup  MISS from PROXYNEW:8080
Via 1.1 PROXYNEW (squid/3.2.3)
Connection  keep-alive
```

Comment: Can you clarify _'but still not working'_? Is the HTTPRequest not made? Is there no result? Is the result not propertly decoded? _'but IE failed to decrypt the data'_ are you using encryption as well?

Comment: Updated in the question itself. Sorry if my post was not clear. The response data size is 14.7KB in all browsers except IE9, whereas in IE9, it is 225KB which is the size of uncompressed data! That is what I meant to say.

Comment: In the IE response there are other headers, notabily the X-Cache headers which seem to imply there is a proxy inbetween. Is that the case, could it be that the proxy deflates the response?

Comment: Let me check that! But how come Cache headers have any impact on gzip header?

Comment: They don't, but a proxy might.

Comment: Proxy wasn't the issue. Tested with other browsers without proxy and all of them working fine except IE9!